# How to connect TX and RX on the ESP8266 to USB pins D- and D+ on the NXP LPC1769?

Tags: esp8266

I have a board (with NXP LPC1769) hosting an application and connected to the PC via USB cable. I use an application running on my PC and communication is pretty straightforward (some ASCII commands are exchanging) and working as it should be.

So, what I would like to achieve is to connect my favorite WIFI module ESP8266 using its TX/RX pins to the USB connector (D- and D+) of the NXP LPC1769 instead of my PC.

You may ask why you don't use any UART pins of the LPC1769. And my answer, I would love to. But it requires pretty much code modification which is not pleasant at this stage for me.

Pins P0.29 and P0.30 used from LPC1769 connected to USB connector.

**Here is the existing schematic;**
[image]

I would like to ask if this is even possible, and if possible, what are the options?

(I am inexperienced with NXP MCUs, still a work in progress, please bear with me).

Thank you.

Comment: That's not how this works. You can't just connect them together because both UART and USB use two pins for data. To make it work you will need additional hardware, which will probably be more work, than modifying your code.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, they can't be connected straight forward. This is why I asked here for a help. Perhaps, I couldn't ask properly ,sorry for that. So, I am open to hardware changes instead of software.

Comment: The nodemcu boards have an esp8266 and a serial to USB chip on them, did you consider using one of those?

Comment: @leetibbett, thank you for your input. I didn't think about it but why not. Are you sure that just connecting the usb connector on the nodemcu to the usb connector on the LPC1769 board straight forward?

Comment: I myself have not tried it.  There would need to be appropriate support for it in your NXP device.

Comment: @leetibbett, in fact that, when we use USB communication, common sense, you will need one side is host and the other side is a device connecting to it. In this case, it looks both sides are devices, there is no host.So, I believe that one side should act like an host USB. After all, USB signals are pretty fast and have different protocol. So, I feel that there is no a simple go for what I want.

Comment: there are cheap avr boards that can host USB, digispark for example

Answer (score 0):

NO my friend, it is simply not possible to connect USB serial to Rx/Tx pins of the ESP8266. First there is the hardware limitation, only asynchronous serial communication is possible with the ESP8266. That device has no USB host in it that can be programmed so there no way to do what you ask simply with that circuit. Nevertheless i would suggest implementing a simply board with a FTDI device of your choice (FT232R for example) and do the conversion from USB to asynchronous serial communication (Rx/Tx) directly.